# Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int**' to 'int*'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, addressof

I'm learning C and C# and this question is for C#. I looking at pointers at msdn and this code is not compiling, it gives the error:Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type `int**` to `int*`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). What am I missing here?

Here is the code:

```
    int ix = 10;
        unsafe
        {
            int* px1;
            int* px2 = &ix;  **The error is on this line**
        }
```

EDIT:
Here is the program in its entirety:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using practice;

class Program
{
  public delegate bool ThisIsTheDelegate(int number);
  public delegate bool ThisIsAnotherDelegate(int number);

  private static string address;

  public static String Address
  {
      get
      {
          return address;
      }
      set
      {
          address = value;
      }
  }

    static void Main()
    {
        int[] someArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
        foreach (int number in someArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }

        int integer = 98;
        string someString = "edited";
        string[] someStr = { "edited" };
        String[] anotherStringSomestr = new String[] { "edited" };

        var readWithLinq = from far in anotherStringSomestr
                           select far;

        foreach (var some in readWithLinq)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(some);
        }

        Program newPro = new Program();
        bool isEven1 = newPro.isEven(99);
        Console.WriteLine(isEven1);
        ThisIsTheDelegate newDelegate = newPro.isEven;
        Console.WriteLine(newDelegate(98));
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        List<int> evenNumbers = FilterArray(numbers, newDelegate);
        foreach(int integer1 in evenNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(integer1);
        }
        List<int> oddNumbers = FilterArray(numbers, isOdd);
        foreach (int integer1 in oddNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(integer1);
        }

        ThisIsAnotherDelegate anotherDelegate;
        anotherDelegate = number => (number % 2 == 0);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a even number", anotherDelegate(4));

        for (int i = 0; i < someString.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(someString);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < someStr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(someStr[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(integer);

        SimpleStruct structss = new SimpleStruct();
        structss.DisplayX();

        M.x = 1;
        structss.x = 98;

        Console.WriteLine(M.x);
        Console.WriteLine(structss.x);

        M.structtaker(ref structss);
        M.classtaker();

        Console.WriteLine(structss.x);
        Console.WriteLine(M.x);

        M.x = 1;
        structss.x = 98;

        int ix = 10;
        unsafe
        {
            int* px1;
            int* px2 = &ix;
        }

        int selection = 98;
        while (selection != 0)
        {
            mainMenu();
            Console.Write("Enter choice: ");
            selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    openSomething();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    calculator();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    coolestProgramEverALive();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    make_to_do_list();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    add_to_do_list();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    readToDoList();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    linq_and_arrays();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    calendar();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    linq_and_collections();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unkown selection. Try again");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool isOdd(int number)
    {
        return (number % 2 == 1);
    }

    private static List<int> FilterArray(int[] numbers, ThisIsTheDelegate newDelegate)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        foreach (int item in numbers)
        {
            if (newDelegate(item))
                result.Add(item);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void linq_and_collections()
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("Billy");
        names.Add("Steve");
        names.Add("Casandra");
        names.Insert(0, "Johanna");
        names.Add("Sonny");
        names.Add("Suzanne");
        names.Insert(2, "Sid");

        var queryLinqUpper = from name in names
                             where (name.StartsWith("S") || name.StartsWith("B") || name.StartsWith("J"))
                             let namesToUpper = name.ToUpper()
                             orderby namesToUpper
                             select namesToUpper;
        foreach (var linqToUpper in queryLinqUpper)
        {
            Console.Write(linqToUpper + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        M.WriteTextToConsole("Hello, world. Programming in C# is fun");
        char c = 'A';
        int count = 14;
        String str = new String(c, count);
        str.WriteTextToConsole();
        M.WriteTextToConsole(str);

    }

    private static void calendar()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private static void readToDoList()
    {
        var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\data", "*.txt")
                    select file;
        int number = 1;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number + ". " + file);
            number++;
        }
        Console.Write("What todolist do you want to read? Give me the name:");
        try
        {
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Address = Path.Combine(@"C:\data", name + ".txt");

            TextReader inFile = new StreamReader(Address);
            while (inFile.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string line = inFile.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            inFile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception thrown!", "Error");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void linq_and_arrays()
    {
        int numberOfElements;
        Console.WriteLine("Start by setting the int[] array.");
        Console.Write("How many elements are there in your array?");
        numberOfElements = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] array = new int[numberOfElements];
        for (int i = 0, j = numberOfElements; i < numberOfElements; i++, j--)
        {
            Console.Write("Integers left to add {0}. Enter an integer:", j);
            array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        var arrayquery = from value in array
                         select value;

        foreach (var val in arrayquery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value from array:{0}", val);
        }

    }

    private static void add_to_do_list()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Which todolist do you want to modify?");
        listToDoLists();
        Console.Write("Enter name of todolist: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Address = Path.Combine(@"C:\data", name + ".txt");
        String tempString;
        StreamWriter stream;
        stream = File.AppendText(Address);
        Console.Write("Enter your new ToDo: ");
        tempString = Console.ReadLine();
        stream.WriteLine(tempString);
        stream.Close();
        TextReader inFile;
        inFile = new StreamReader(Address);
        while (inFile.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string line = inFile.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        inFile.Close();
    }

    private static void listToDoLists()
    {
        int filenumber = 1;
        string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\data\\", "*.txt");
        foreach (string file in filepaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filenumber + ". " + file);
            filenumber++;
        }
    }

    private static void make_to_do_list()
    {
        string path, name;
        string yesOrNo;
        Console.Write("Enter name of todolist: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        path = Path.Combine(@"C:\data", name + ".txt");
        TextWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(path);
        labelOne:  // else clause : unknown answer
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add something to todolist.Y/N?");
        yesOrNo = Console.ReadLine();
        if (yesOrNo.ToLower() == "y")
        {
            string line;
            int lines;
            Console.Write("How many lines?");
            lines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a line of text: ");
                line = Console.ReadLine();
                outFile.WriteLine(line);
            }
            outFile.Close();
        }
        else if (yesOrNo.ToLower() == "n")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You can close the application now.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown answer. Try again");
            goto labelOne;
        }
    }

    private static void coolestProgramEverALive()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\KristjanBEstur\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\The_coolest_program_ever_alive\The_coolest_program_ever_alive\obj\Debug\The_coolest_program_ever_alive.exe");
    }

    private static void calculator()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc");
    }

    private static void openSomething()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad");
    }

    private static void mainMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("0. Quit");
        Console.WriteLine("1. OpenSomething");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("3. coolestProgramEverAlive");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Make todolist");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Add to todolist");
        Console.WriteLine("6. Read to do list");
        Console.WriteLine("7. Linq and arrays");
        Console.WriteLine("8. Calendar");
        Console.WriteLine("9. Linq and collections");
    }


    public bool isEven(int number)
    {
        return (number % 2 == 0);
    }
}

static class M
{
    public static int x;

  public static void WriteTextToConsole(this string text)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(text);
  }

  public static void structtaker(ref SimpleStruct s)
  {
      s.x = 5;
  }
  public static void classtaker()
  {
      M.x = 5;
  }
  }

 class Test
 {
   static int value = 20;
   unsafe static void F(out int* pi1, ref int* pi2) {
  int i = 10;
  pi1 = &i;
  fixed (int* pj = &value) {
     // ...
     pi2 = pj;
  }
    }
 }

struct SimpleStruct
{
public int x;
private int xval;
public int X
{
    get 
    {
        return xval;
    }
    set 
    {
        if (value < 100)
            xval = value;
    }
}
public void DisplayX()
{
    Console.WriteLine("The stored value is: {0}", X);
}
```

}

Comment: That code compiles fine by itself.  It must be some surrounding code which is causing the problem.  Can you expand your code sample a bit?

Comment: You're probably using `&x` in an `x` that's a pointer. But your example does not exhibit this issue.

Comment: That full code sample you posted also compiles just fine.

Comment: Produce a [small self contained example](http://sscce.org). Remove unrelated code, check if problem is still there, repeat. Until the smallest possible program that exhibits the problem remains. But as far as I can tell, the full code you posted should work.

Comment: There is a blue squiggly line under "&ix" in visual studio, I can't imagine what the problem can be? The code in the question the code snippet is all that this code does so far, I haven't used the Test class yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved the expression "int i = 10;" out of the unsafe block and now it compiles. I've also put the code in question in a new project of another instance of vs2012pro. And that also compiles. So now I'm unable to replicate the error.

Here is the code:

```
        int ix = 10;
        unsafe
        {               
            int* px1;
            int* px2 = &ix;
            Test.F(out px1, ref px2);
            Console.WriteLine("*px1 = {0}, *px2 = {1}",
               *px1, *px2);   // undefined behavior
        }
```

Here is the other project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace saxerium
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int ix = 10;
        unsafe
        {
            int* px1;
            int* px2 = &ix;
            Test.F(out px1, ref px2);
            Console.WriteLine("*px1 = {0}, *px2 = {1}",
               *px1, *px2);   // undefined behavior
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static int value = 20;
    public unsafe static void F(out int* pi1, ref int* pi2)
    {
        int i = 10;
        pi1 = &i;
        fixed (int* pj = &value)
        {
            // ...
            pi2 = pj;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I wished I could replicate this it seems like a rather interesting issue.  Here is the section of the standard that I believe applies to this (sorry about the formatting):

> 18.3 Fixed and moveable variables The address-of operator (§18.5.4) and the fixed statement (§18.6) divide variables into two categories:
>   Fixed variables and moveable variables. Fixed variables reside in
>   storage locations that are unaffected by operation of the garbage
>   collector. (Examples of fixed variables include local variables, value
>   parameters, and variables created by dereferencing pointers.) On the
>   other hand, moveable variables reside in storage locations that are
>   subject to relocation or disposal by the garbage collector. (Examples
>   of moveable variables include fields in objects and elements of
>   arrays.) The & operator (§18.5.4) permits the address of a fixed
>   variable to be obtained without restrictions. However, because a
>   moveable variable is subject to relocation or disposal by the garbage
>   collector, the address of a moveable variable can only be obtained
>   using a fixed statement (§18.6), and that address remains valid only
>   for the duration of that fixed statement. In precise terms, a fixed
>   variable is one of the following: •   A variable resulting from a
>   simple-name (§7.6.2) that refers to a local variable or a value
>   parameter, unless the variable is captured by an anonymous function.
>   • A variable resulting from a member-access (§7.6.4) of the form V.I,
>   where V is a fixed variable of a struct-type. •   A variable resulting
>   from a pointer-indirection-expression (§18.5.1) of the form *P, a
>   pointer-member-access (§18.5.2) of the form P->I, or a
>   pointer-element-access (§18.5.3) of the form P[E]. All other variables
>   are classified as moveable variables. Note that a static field is
>   classified as a moveable variable. Also note that a ref or out
>   parameter is classified as a moveable variable, even if the argument
>   given for the parameter is a fixed variable. Finally, note that a
>   variable produced by dereferencing a pointer is always classified as a
>   fixed variable.

I spend some time trying to create a similar error but wasn't about to.  The only way I was able to recreate the issue was with the following code:

```
    void test() {
        int ix = 10;
        unsafe {
            int* px1 = &ix;
            int* px2 = &px1; // **The error is on this line**
            }
        }
```

Of course this code cannot be fixed by moving the ix declaration into the safe scope.  Perhaps you could try replicating the original problem in a very small bit of code (like above) and verify that both the problem and the fix replicate.  Perhaps VS became confused.  I have had problems that made no sense and went away by exiting VS and restarting (not often but a few times).

Answer (score 0):

I moved the i declaration down inside the unsafe block and it fixed it, I don't know why?

Here is the code:

```
    unsafe
    {   
        int ix = 10;
        int* px1;
        int* px2 = &ix;
    }
```

Comment: That is odd.  I tried this in VS2012 and 2013, but could not replicate your error.  Want version of C# (and tools) are you using?